# Change android seekbar value without clicking direclty on the seekbar thumb

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop, seekbar, seekbar-thumb

I have an android seekbar that appears on the screen when a user touches a button.

How can I start tracking user touch to move the seekbar immediately  after it appears?

To be more clear, essentially I want the user to be able to move the seekbar thumb/progress without clicking directly on it.

Answer (score -1):

`Seekbar` extends `ProgressBar`, so just call `setProgress` on your `SeekBar` to update it.

See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar) for reference.